# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (Script Ajax Call)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, aem

i'm doing in `CQ5`, a component that connect with a servlet and get this info:

> Output Servlet (json format)= [{"text":"A","value":10},{"text":"B","value":20}]

for show A and B in a drop down menu.

This my html code:

```
<div>
   <form action="/bin/company/repo" method="post">
        <select id="options">
        </select>
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">  
    </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

For insert the options (select), i do this javascript in the jsp of component:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#options');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    $.ajax({
      url: '/bin/company/repo',
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option
        $.each(data, function(text, value){
          $select.append('<option id="' + value.value + '">' + value.text + '</option>');
        });
      },
      error:function(){
        //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
        $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
      }
    });
</script>
```

But I get `Uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function`. Maybe I have an error of syntax in my script code. How can I solve?

Comment: its true but uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function is the problem now </strong> was an error typing the question :I

Comment: Okay... could have been then answer

Comment: Your debugger should tell you which line the error is on.

Comment: You are using an id for your select options, should be class since it is not unique.

Comment: before error:function(){ in " }, " in this place i get Uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function according debugger.

Comment: Looks correct, are you sure you have jQuery included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a conflict between 2 jQuery:

We can delete one or modify the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    //get a reference to the select element
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    j.ajax({
            url: '/bin/company/repo',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(data){
              //clear the current content of the select
              j('#abcd').html('');
              //iterate over the data and append a select option
              jQuery.each(data, function(text, value){
                 j('#abcd').append('<option id="' + value.value + '">' + value.text + '</option>');
              });
            },
            error:function(){
               //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
               j('#abcd').html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
            }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work, only problem I found was that you are not specifying a request type in your AJAX call.

Just add: `type: 'post',`

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soytfuer/1/).

Comment: yep this is the next step now but its work now. i fix it as i writed in my post, thanks!.

Comment: Sorry the fiddle wasn't working, forgot to update it :)

Comment: read my post where explain there are a conflict between 2 jQuery